# Outline Text with Word Interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I have searched online and on SO and can't find anybody else asking about this which I found a little surprising; perhaps my search query is off.

I am trying to add the 'Outline' effect (as seen under the Text Effects drop-down on the Home ribbon) without luck. There is an [Outline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._font.outline(v=office.14).aspx) property on Font, but I've tried setting it to to 1 with no effect. The Glow and Reflection effects are configurable (e.g. Font.Glow.Radius, Font.Glow.Color).

I got excited when I saw the Font.Borders property

```
range[j].Font.Borders.Enable = 1;
range[j].Font.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
range[j].Font.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth100pt;
range[j].Font.Borders.OutsideColor = WdColor.wdColorBlack;
```

But this was just a rectangular border around the text itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Font.Outline = True` // value is probably -1 in C# rather than 1

`Font.Line.ForeColor` //and use `.RGB` or .`ObjectThemeColor` to specify the color, keeping in mind that you need to "translate" the RGB color between COM and .NET.

Comment: Hi Cindy - setting to -1 doesn't appear to have made it work; looking at the document still shows the text as having 'No Outline'. Additionally, attempting to set `Font.Line.ForeColor` results in an error stating it is read-only (EDIT: I'm dumb, testing with the .RGB property now)

Comment: `.Font.Outline = -1;`
`.Font.Line.Weight = 0.5f;`
`range[j].Font.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = WdThemeColorIndex.wdThemeColorMainDark1;`

Is what ended up working for me, thanks!